# How to get an object to list

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

I use exchange method for get a some API data

And then I parsing jason.

I can't parsing Object data

I also use getForObject method too.

But that method didn't solved.

How to I get JSON parsing data?

I do want to to insert local Database under "kds"

Call other API

```
String theUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api-datas";
     HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(new MediaType[] { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON }));
     headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

       ResponseEntity<Entity> response = restTemplate.exchange(theUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Entity.class);

--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Entity.class is

  @Transient
    private Object meta;
    @Transient
    private Object body;



    @Transient
    private List<EntityList> kds = new ArrayList<>();



    JsonParser springParser = JsonParserFactory.getJsonParser();
 Map<String, Object> map = springParser.parseMap(String.valueOf(response.getBody()));
```

like this

```
{
    “meta”:
         {
          "result":true,
          "code":200,
           "msg":"",
           },
   “body”:
     {
      “kds”:
        [
        {
       "key":"some-keys",
       "data":
             {
              "sender":"some-mail",
              "receiver":"some-mail",
              "response":”200 OK”,
              "title":"some-title"
              }
            },
        "key":"some-keys",
        "data":
              {
              "sender":"some-mail",
              "receiver":"some-mail",
              "response":”200 OK”,
              "title":"some-title"
              }
            },
         }
        ]
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you use like this

```
JSONParser paser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) paser.parse(response.getBody());
        JSONObject parse_meta = (JSONObject) obj.get("meta");
        JSONObject parse_body = (JSONObject) obj.get("body");
        JSONArray  parse_kds = (JSONArray ) parse_body.get("kds");


        parse_kds.stream().forEach(
                (getKds)->{
                    JSONObject parse_key = (JSONObject) getKds;
                    JSONObject parse_data = (JSONObject) getKds;
                    String key = (String) parse_key.get("key");
                    System.out.println(key);
                }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

what i understand from your question that you are calling resttemplate  execute method and after you got the response as a json you want to pasre the json and insert in db,
you can look at objectmapper to parse json and get some specific code value like in you case "kds"

you can try

```
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode Node = objectMapper.readTree(response.getBody());
        JsonNode rootList = Node.path("body").path("kds");
        ObjectReader reader = objectMapper.readerFor(new TypeReference<List<EntityList>>() {
        });
        List<EntityList> listOfValues = reader.readValue(rootList);
```

Comment: Thank you~!.
You're advice save my time

Comment: @user3066285 if it has helped you can you just upvote it, so others can also pint in right direction